# 'MatFormFieldModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, ivy, ng-modules

Im getting this error importing angular material.

> 'MatFormFieldModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
> form-field-module.d.ts(10, 3): This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatFormFieldModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

My dependencies:

````
```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.18
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.18
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.9
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    12.2.9
@angular/material               12.2.13
@schematics/angular             12.2.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```
````

I already tried:

- "postinstall": "ngcc"
- remove node_modules, clear cache, install node_modules
- different versions of angular cli and angular material

My shared.module.ts:

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatFormFieldModule
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Comment: You should post your component where you are getting this error, so we can see what is missing.

Comment: Also, did you import MatFormFieldModule into the module that is actually using it?

Comment: @FunkMonkey33, thank you for the reply. Yes, Im importing into the module that is using it. I even tried to do it in app.module, but same error.

Comment: @FunkMonkey33, new information added

Comment: Here's a dumb question for you: are you actually importing the SharedModule into your AppModule (assuming "AppModule" is your root module, and that that's where the problem is appearing).

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code in your shared module.

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material/form-field";
    
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatFormFieldModule
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Comment: I appreciate it. It was already like that, sorry. I had paste it wrong in the question's body. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- deleted "node_modules"
- deleted "package-lock.json"
- npm i